# Including virtuals in query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema `MySchema` on which I have defined virtuals. When I query for documents based on `MySchema`, the documents' properties do not include the virtual ones. How can I specify that I want my query result to include the virtual properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virtuals are there, they just don't show up as properties of the Model object. I assume you're trying something like `console.log(results),` and you're right, you won't see the virtuals there. But if you do something like:

```
Model.findOne( query, function (err, doc){
  console.log(doc.myVirtual);
});
```

Then you'll see the virtuals if you've defined them properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the `toObject` function to return a plain object with the virtual values:

```
doc.toObject({ virtuals: true });
```

More information on the [API docs of mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject).